# Modelling GLM in R with discrete non-binary response

Tags: r, glm

I'm new to R and I would like to model the following in GLM:

A memory retention experiment where I ask each participant a similar question every X days. The question has either a correct or wrong answer, the participant must keep trying until the answer is correct. I want to find the probability of him answering the question correctly in 1 try given the past data of number of tries and the time offset between questions.

I'm following this tutorial to model it:
http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-tutorial-glm1/

Here's an example of a part of my table

```
0 3 -
1 1 2
0 2 1
0 5 4
1 1 2
```

The first value is a binary value whether he 'passes' or 'fails'. Answering in 1 attempt is pass and more than that is fail.

The second value is the number of attempts. We can see that if it is 1 then the first value is also 1, else, the first value is 0.

The third value is the number of days between the question and the previous question.

Right now I'm modelling it as

```
first ~ second + third
```

I was thinking if there is a better way to do it, since the first is directly related to the second value. Something like only using the second and third value, and finding P(second = 1). And eventually I would also like to find P(second = 2) in the future.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I think that the first success after multiple prior failed attempts where the probability of a success is Normally distributed has an Erlang distribution. I think you could model the  `first+second` as Poisson distributed with `third` as a covariate. You would need to do a residual analysis. Close vote explanation: I think this is not really a coding question but rather one the should have been address to CrossValidated.com.

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, this model is perfectly fit with the second column because column 2 equaling 1 is a necessary and sufficient condition for column 1 equaling 1. 

I think what you want is to model past values in a panel data set right? So you don't care about Person A's # of tries in answering the question at time t in your regression, you care about their # of tries leading up to that question so the sum of tries from t=0 to t=t-1.

Comment: Hi, yes you are correct. I don't really care if how many tries Person A takes on time t, I just want to know, based on the # of tries from t=0 to t=t-1, as well as the differences in the intervals of doing the question, the probability of him getting it right on the first try at time t.